# Stuck with calling Jquery function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this code :

```
<div id='mainTop'>                 
    <span></span>
    <button><h3>Search</h3></button>
    <div class='inputField'><input type='text' name='search' size=45></div>
</div>

<script>
    function showPage(page,key)    {   
        if(!key)
            $.get("showPage.php?page="+page,function(data){
                /**
                 *    Insert HTML result from PHP file
                 *    Then edit table color
                 *    In the end call function buttonPage()
                 */
                $("#mainTable").html(data);
                $("#mainTable tr:odd td").css("background-color","#e3f0ad");
                buttonPage(page);
            });
        else
            $.get("showPage.php?page="+page+"&key="+key,function(data){
                $("#mainTable").html(data);
                $("#mainTable tr:odd td").css("background-color","#e3f0ad");
                buttonPage(page,key);
            });
    }

    $("#mainTop button").click(function(){
        key= $("#mainTop input").val();
        if(!key)
            showPage(1,key);
    });
</script>
```

What I want is to have a input field and a button to search through database.
If key are null then I dont pass key parameter to php file and just printout the database.
If key are not null then pass key parameter to php file and use that key to search in database.

I tried to ran the php file by itself and it work,but when I click the button nothing happen,so I think my script has some problems.Can someone help me out ?

Comment: Please check your browser's Javascript console for errors. Also, `$.get` has a `data` parameter, so you shouldn't assemble the query string by yourself.

Comment: Also I believe that the callback (`function(data){...}`) should be the third parameter to `get`, not the second?

Comment: How to check browser's Javascript console for errors ? I only know to use CTRL-Shift-J but there is no error

Comment: $.get can be used like this, it is not the problem. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: @kos  data and callback parameters are optional. Also nothing wrong with creating data string in url

Comment: @charlietfl if JQuery does some voodoo to allow skipping optional args other than last, then that's OK. Creating data strings in URL is only OK if you know what you're doing (i.e. [encode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) the data correctly)

Comment: @kos   optional args are common in jQuery API. Agree is simpler to use a data object but url gets encoded by jQuery also

Answer (score 0):

In the function where you bind your click you are checking that `key` is falsy before calling `showPage`. So despite your check for `key` *inside* of `showPage()` (which always makes a request but decides whether or not to send the key), you never get into `showPage()` if you  provide anyhing in your input.

This code:

```
$("#mainTop button").click(function(){
    key= $("#mainTop input").val();
    if(!key)
        showPage(1,key);
});
```

Should probably be:

```
$("#mainTop button").click(function(){
    key = $("#mainTop input").val();

    showPage(1,key);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You not set the button click event... add the Onclick event to your html code...

```
<button onclick="showPage()"><h3>Search</h3></button>
```

Comment: The click is bound programmatically by jQuery within the script block (the portion using `.click`).

Answer (score 0):

Your code must be corrected as below

```
$("#mainTop button").click(function(){
   var key= $("#mainTop input").val();  
    if(key)
        showPage(1,key);
});
```

Comment: This only allows `showPage` to run if a value is provided in the input. Per the question, it should run regardless of what is in the input, even if it is empty.